# What does 'gutter' refer to in the phrase 'throw money in the gutter'?

Tags: idioms, nouns

Below are the images of the definition of gutter on Google, which is a trough on the edge of a roof. However, in the phrase 'throw money in the gutter', I imagine gutter means something related to sewage.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_gutter

Comment: @KillingTime That's an answer not a comment.

Comment: Hint: You don't go UP to have your  "head/mind in the gutter" or to "spit in the gutter." *Sewer* is the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When something goes into a gutter, it eventually goes down the drain, rendering it irretrievable.

Bye, money!

> **gutter** *noun*
> **1a** : a trough along the eaves to catch and carry off rainwater
> **b** : a low area (as at the edge of a street) to carry off surface water (as to a sewer)
> **c** : a trough or groove to catch and direct something
>  <sub>Source:
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gutter)</sub>

It doesn’t much matter what kind of gutter or which drain. However, unless you’re a roof rat, you’re more likely to be engaging a metaphorical street gutter for your “throwdown”:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Gutter](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gutter)

> the edge of a road where rain flows away

In older times, without trash collection and good plumbing, it would be a filthy place full of rubbish.

Comment: Just to confirm, the whole edge of the road (like in the pic) is called a gutter whereas the opening that water flows into is called a drain?

Comment: Yes.  The edge of the road is the gutter.  Even if there isn't a drain.